# Installing Django with mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I wrote an application using Django 1.0. It works fine with the django test server. But when I tried to get it into a more likely production enviroment the Apache server fails to run the app.
The server I use is [WAMP2.0](http://www.wampserver.com). I've been a PHP programmer for years now and I've been using WAMPServer since long ago.
I installed the mod_wsgi.so and seems to work just fine (no services error) but I can't configure the httpd.conf to look at my python scripts located outside the server root.

For now, I'm cool with overriding the document root and serve the django app from the document root instead so the httpd.conf line should look like this:

```
    WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Users/Marcos/Documents/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
```

but the server's response is a 403 Forbidden

Comment: Are you now saying you had a typo when you were using '/C:/...'. If that is the case, acknowledge that you edited your question and fixed it else it gets confusing as to why I was pointing it out as wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /C:/Users/Marcos/Documents/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
```

That is wrong as RHS is not a valid Windows pathname. Use:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / C:/Users/Marcos/Documents/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
```

That is, no leading slash before the Windows drive specifier.

Other than that, follow the mod_wsgi documentation others have pointed out.

---

Poster edited question to change what now would appear to be a typo in the post and not a problem with his configuration.

If that is the case, next causes for a 403 are as follows.

First is that you need to also have:

```
<Directory C:/Users/Marcos/Documents/mysite/apache>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

If you don't have that then Apache isn't being granted rights to serve a script from that directory and so will return FORBIDDEN (403).

Second is that you do have that, but don't acknowledge that you do, and that that directory or the WSGI script file is not readable by the user that the Apache service runs as under Windows.

Comment: Thanks... Such an idiot mistake! ;)
Sorry for the typo before

Answer (score 6):

Have you seen http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango ?

You need more than one line to assure that Apache will play nicely.

```
Alias /media/ /usr/local/django/mysite/media/

<Directory /usr/local/django/mysite/media>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/django/mysite/apache/django.wsgi

<Directory /usr/local/django/mysite/apache>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The `<Directory>`, as well as appropriate file system ownership and permissions are essential.

The `usr/local/django/mysite/apache` directory has your Python/Django app and the all-important `django.wsgi` file.  You must provide permissions on this directory.

Comment: Alias /media/ /usr/local/django/mysite/media/ and first directory are there to serve static content directly bypassing wsgi

what's the last <Directory> for?

Comment: The last directory is your Python/Django app and the `.wsgi` file.

Answer (score 1):

mod_wsgi's documentation is very good. Try using their quick configuration guide and go from there:
http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide