# Deploy django app with domain and subdomains using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, apache, subdomain, mod-wsgi

I am new to django and this is my first project in django. So far, I have developed a django app. It is working fluently in my local machine  but I’m unable to deploy it online.

I have seen many tutorials on internet for deploying the app on server. But none of them seems to be working to me. May be I’m doing something wrong over here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBMVVruB9Vs
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-local-django-app-to-a-vps
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-django-with-mod_wsgi-and-apache-with-a-virtualenv-python-environment-on-a-debian-vps

I followed these tutorials and tried to deploy the app on the server but I always gets 403 forbidden error. I tried to remove this error and referred other stackoverflow answer as well but no success..

[403 Forbidden error with Django and mod_wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766595/403-forbidden-error-with-django-and-mod-wsgi)

[Apache mod_wsgi error: Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4807176/apache-mod-wsgi-error-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-s)

[Django on apache wtih mod_wsgi (Linux) - 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382666/django-on-apache-wtih-mod-wsgi-linux-403-forbidden)

[Installing Django with mod_wsgi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195260/installing-django-with-mod-wsgi)

Here is the structure that i created for my django project. I have two apps in my django project and I’m connecting my one app connect with DNS `xyz.com` and my second app connect with its subdomain `abc.xyz.com`.

Structure

```
project_folder
|
|->app1
|      |->urls.py
|      |->template_folder
|      |->static_folder
|->app2
|     |->urls.py
|     |->template_folder
|     |->static_folder
|->project_name
      |->urls.py
      |->wsgi.py

project_name/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^app1/', include('app1.urls')),
    url(r'^app2/', include('app2.urls')),
]

app1/urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^example1/', views.example1),
    url(r'^example2/', views.example2),
)

app2/urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^example3/', views.example3),
    url(r'^example4/', views.example4),
)
```

Basically what I’m trying to do is that my `app1` runs on `xyz.com` and my `app2` runs on `abc.xyz.com` (sub domain). So that all app in the project having same user login. If a user login from one app it will be logged in the second app also.

On my local machine the app runs as

http://localhost:8000/app1

http://localhost:8000/app1/example1

http://localhost:8000/app1/example2

http://localhost:8000/app2/example3

http://localhost:8000/app2/example4

Here is my apache2 conf file that i create on my server

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName xyz.com

DocumentRoot /home/user_name/project_folder/

<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    AddHandler mod_python .py
    PythonHandler mod_python.publisher | .py
    PythonDebug On
</Directory>

<Directory /home/user_name/project_folder/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /home/user_name/project_folder/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /home/user_name/project_folder/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You don't seem to have anything in your Apache config to actually serve your site at all. Mod_python has been deprecated for years and is not supported by Django.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm new to this. Hence doesn't have much information about it. Can you please recommend any correct way to deal with this situation ?

Comment: But you said you'd read all those tutorials. You don't seem to have followed any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Daniel Roseman was right with the comment. I went thru the document over again and tried with the way it is mentioned in the pages. And I finally resolved the issue.

This is how I resolved it..

`app1.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xyz.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/project_folder/project_name/wsgi.py

    WSGIDaemonProcess xyz.com python-path=/var/www/html/project_folder:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup xyz.com

    <Directory /var/www/html/project_folder/project_name>
            <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable the `app1.conf` file using command `sudo a2ensite app1.conf`.

For domain and subdomain i used django package [django-subdomains](http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

`setting.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites', # For include sites
    'app1',
    'ap2',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'subdomains.middleware.SubdomainURLRoutingMiddleware', # Subdomain package
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

SITE_ID = 1

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app1.urls'

SUBDOMAIN_URLCONFS = {
    None: 'app1.urls',
    'www': 'app1.urls',
    'abc': 'app2.urls',
}
```

After all settings done run command `python manage.py migrate`. It will create `django_site` table in database with one entry. Change `example.com` to `xyz.com`.

For subdomain create new `app2.conf` file and change `xyz.com` to `abc.xyz.com`.